# Look-up table of C macros

Tags: c, macros, lookup-tables

I'm making look-up tables between 2 drivers. I use an enum starting at index 0, which is passed to a look-up table to return an integer. This works fine.

```
// In library
#define LIB_FEATURE_1 0x10
#define LIB_FEATURE_2 0x22
#define LIB_FEATURE_3 0x44
#define LIB_FEATURE_4 0x42

// In my costum driver
enum features_s {
    my_feature_a = 0,
    my_feature_b = 1,
    my_feature_c = 2
};

const int feature_tbl[] = {
    LIB_FEATURE_2,   // Maps my_feature_a to LIB_FEATURE_2
    0xFF,            // Maps my_feature_b to an error code because this  
                     //     feature is not present in library
    LIB_FEATURE_4    // Maps my_feature_c to LIB_FEATURE_4
};

// In app
int value = feature_tbl[my_feature_a];
```

The library contains some more complicated macros (setting registers in an embedded system) :

```
// In library
#define LIB_FEATURE_1 do {
                    //does black magic
                } while(0)

#define LIB_FEATURE_2 do {
                    //does white magic
                } while(0)

#define LIB_FEATURE_3 do {
                    //does yellow magic
                } while(0)

#define LIB_FEATURE_4 do {
                    //does purple magic
                } while(0)

// In my costum driver
enum features_s {
    my_feature_a = 0,
    my_feature_b = 1,
    my_feature_c = 2
};

/* 
 * something missing here. I want this mapping :
 * my_feature_a executes LIB_FEATURE_2();
 * my_feature_b executes nothing
 * my_feature_c executes LIB_FEATURE_4();
 */

// In app
SOME_KIND_OF_LOOK_UP_TABLE[my_feature_a]();
```

Is it possible to create a const table, or a macro that takes an index as argument and executes the right feature?

I also tried macro concatenation, but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried using a const table, and a macro concatenations

Comment: macros are text replacements pre compile time. They don't exist as entities of their own at runtime. You might consider instead an array of function pointers. The function bodies would be what your macros are now. Another alternative would be to write a function (or large macro) that has a switch with the different cases calling the different macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Runtime version:**

```
//function prototype
typedef void (*my_lib_feature_function)();

//implement feature functions
//we need an address, therefore real functions instead of macros
static void my_lib_feature_function_1() { /* feature magic 1 */ }
static void my_lib_feature_function_2() { /* feature magic 2 */ }
static void my_lib_feature_function_3() { /* feature magic 3 */ }
static void my_lib_feature_function_4() { /* feature magic 4 */ }

//feature table (lookup table)
//organize as you see fit, extend or shorten it, but
//take care of the right indices (enum values)
static const my_lib_feature_function function_table[] = {
    my_lib_feature_function_2, //index 0 -> my_feature_a
    NULL,                      //index 1 -> my_feature_b
    my_lib_feature_function_4  //index 2 -> my_feature_c
};

//invoker
//param feature is the index to the lookup table
static void invoke_my_lib_feature(enum features_s feature)
{
    if (function_table[feature] != NULL) //if entry exists
        function_table[feature]();       //execute it
}

//In app
/*either*/ //invoke_my_lib_feature(my_feature_a);
/*and/or*/ //invoke_my_lib_feature(my_feature_b);
/*and/or*/ //invoke_my_lib_feature(my_feature_c);
```

**Compiletime version:**

```
//pp util (concatenation)
#define CAT(A,B) CAT_(A,B)
#define CAT_(A,B) A##B

//instead of enum (unfortunately, we can't use enum values here)
#define MY_FEATURE_A 0
#define MY_FEATURE_B 1
#define MY_FEATURE_C 2

//feature table
#define LIB_FEATURE_ENTRY_0 LIB_FEATURE_2 //-> MY_FEATURE_A
#define LIB_FEATURE_ENTRY_1 //empty       //-> MY_FEATURE_B
#define LIB_FEATURE_ENTRY_2 LIB_FEATURE_4 //-> MY_FEATURE_C

//invoker
#define INVOKE_LIB_FEATURE(IDX) CAT(LIB_FEATURE_ENTRY_,IDX)

//In App
/*either*/ //INVOKE_LIB_FEATURE(MY_FEATURE_A); //expands to text after LIB_FEATURE_2
/*and/or*/ //INVOKE_LIB_FEATURE(MY_FEATURE_B); //empty
/*and/or*/ //INVOKE_LIB_FEATURE(MY_FEATURE_C); //expands to text after LIB_FEATURE_4
```

Comment: Spot on! Encapsulating the macros in a function table was right what I was missing.
My look-up tables are in a .h file, should I declare the my_lib_feature_function_x functions in the .h as well? I wouldn't want the user to call them directly

Comment: @john_hatten2 you have the invoker. yes, i would not declare them publicly. To be clear, the constants (enums) and the invoker are public, the table and the function implementations go into the source file (that would be the strategy for encapsulation). If for any reason, they have to be declared public as well, then i would introduce a separate header (which makes it somehow clear, that this is intended for internal use only).